# Can error correcting codes be used to guess this plaintext?

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis

I pick a finite set of messages, perhaps the set of integers $M = \lbrace n \in \mathbf{Z} \, : \, 0 \leq n\lt10 \rbrace$, which you are then allowed to encode in any way you want (some form of [error correcting code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_detection_and_correction) is assumed), transforming $M$ into a set of equal size, $P$, which you send back to me. Then, without your knowledge, I select a single $p \in P$ from your encodings, to which I apply an encryption operation under a key that transforms your $p$ into $p'$. To what extent are you able to determine the original message that I selected given

- a) You have full knowledge of the algorithm used and the key is known.
- b) Same as (a), except that one of two possible keys have been used.
- c) Same as (a), except that you have no knowledge of the key.

No particular symmetric cipher is specified. I am interested in the general information theoretic properties that make this decoding possible or impossible.

Comment: is the encoding function and the set of messages known to the person doing the encryption? does the "encrypter" then return $p'$ to the "encoder"?

Comment: The encryption operation is fixed and no effort is made to disrupt the particular encoding technique used by the "player". Conversely, the player is allowed to choose an encoding technique tailored to maximize recovery for that particular cipher. $p'$ is returned to the player, who should decode it using any means.

Comment: Case (b) reminds me of [deniable encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/deniable_encryption) algorithms.